# igraph and trying to get names of nodes in a cluster

Tags: networking, cluster-computing, nodes, igraph

I have a network `(Ex: A->B , B->C , J->K, etc)`  So some are connected like `A` to `B` to `C` and some just have one link like `J` to `K`. I created my network using igraph ( `get_graph_from_data_frame`). I used the `clusters()$csize` to see how many separate clusters exist and how many nodes in each. I was hoping to get the name of those node. Is there anyway to do this? I just want to be able to ID how many are only connected to another node or how many are connected to a make of 2 node.

Here is my code:

```
network_billing <- data.frame( Billing_tree$Source, Billing_tree$Target)
net_billing <- graph_from_data_frame(d=network_billing)
library(cluster)
clusters1 <- clusters(net_billing)$csize
clusters1 <- as.data.frame(clusters1)
```

I have how many clusters and the nodes in each. Is there a function to pull those node names out of each cluster?

Answer (score 0):

You do not provide your data, so I am providing a very simple graph as an example.

```
library(igraph)

relations <- data.frame(from=c("Bob", "Cecil", "Cecil", "David",
                               "David", "Esmeralda", "Tom", "Tom"),
                        to=c("Alice", "Bob", "Alice", "Alice", "Bob", 
                    "Alice", "Dick", "Harry"))
g <- graph_from_data_frame(relations)
plot(g)
```

[image: Network with 2 components]

Now we can get the components that you want.

```
clusters1 = clusters(g)
V(g)[clusters1$membership == 1]
+ 5/8 vertices, named, from 42645a7:
[1] Bob       Cecil     David     Esmeralda Alice    
V(g)[clusters1$membership == 2]
+ 3/8 vertices, named, from 42645a7:
[1] Tom   Dick  Harry
```